# flask multi user authentication with multiple table

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login, multi-user

I need your help please,
I have in my models file, 3 tables of 3 different kinds of users (admins, clients, company) and each user can have an email and password for authentication. The problem is that when a user creates a count in 2 tables, say clients and company, with a same email, the program confuses between to count and gives an error :

```
 - class Admin(UserMixin, db.Model):   
 - class Client(UserMixin, db.Model): 
 - class Company(UserMixin, db.Model):
```

Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: You can Just Change permission <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973490/multiple-user-for-flask-login">see here for more</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so this is a design flaw with your database. Different types of users should not be stored in different places.

You need to define a model where the type of user is defined within the database. You can then create methods within your model class to evaluate the user class and decide how to treat it.

Example:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(200), unique = True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200))
    userType = db.Column(db.String(20), default = 'user') #can be user, client, admin or whatever your options are

    def isAdmin(self): #an example method - your admin view could use this method to check if a user should be given access
         if self.userType == 'admin':
             return True
         else:
             return False
```

Comment: i have a similar problem, but only one of user types should have a foreign key to other tables, how could i do that ? inheritance ?