# multiple user for flask_login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have two user models for flask_login.:

```
class Admin(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(200))

class Merchant(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(200))
```

Now I want to load user in session:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    pass
```

I want to know how to load user from two models.

Comment: These two users just seem definitely the same except for their class names. I think what you want is to determine users' permissions. In this case, you can just add a property named `permission` which could be `admin` or `normal user` or something else.

Comment: It looks like you want to merge authentication and authorization into one. This is usually a bad idea. Authentication (securely identify the user) goes first and then you think about authorization (give permissions to the identified user). Also, how are you going to reference a user when there are two tables? Or how do you promote a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#You can create a permission 
admin_permission = Permission(RoleNeed('admin'))

#protect a view with a principal for that need
@app.route('/admin')
@admin_permission.required()
def do_admin_index():
     return Response('Only if you are an admin)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: The following link https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/ provides a good explanation to this answer, which is using Flask-Principal.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution I've been using so far; I don't know it's flaws, but it's the answer you're looking for.

Assuming you have multiple account types, the key is to use the session to store that account type upon login, and use it like this:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
  if session['account_type'] == 'Admin':
      return Admin.query.get(int(user_id))
  elif session['account_type'] == 'Merchant':
      return Merchant.query.get(int(user_id))
  else:
      return None
```

Providing routes and html is not necessary; you could implement them as you wish, either by:

- Creating different routes for different user types.
- Adding a select field in the login form with one route for all user types.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514352/is-it-safe-to-store-user-id-within-the-flask-session) provides further information about sessions and how to secure them; you should check it out.

I understand that your choice to keep your classes separated, but consider merging the common attributes together in one parent class leaving only the id to prevent foreign keys problems, like this:

```
class Person(db.Model):
  __abstract__ = True
  name = db.Column(db.String(30))
  password_hash = db.Column(db.String(200))

class Admin(Person, UserMixin):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Merchant(Person, UserMixin):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

As the parent table is abstract it won't be created, but its children will.

Comment: What is `'account_type'` in `session`? The rest of `user_loader` I can understand.

Comment: @GitauHarrison `session` is a cookie that stores **key-value** pairs, you can add any pair with this line of code `session['key']='value'`.


`account_type` is just a **key** that has a **value** of either `Admin` or `Merchant` inside the `session` cookie, it is initialized upon login in, and tested later on to **give/prohibit** access to some routes in our website.