# sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type integer: "B1"

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am tryng to login the admin on my flask app using ID, when i signup it is taking inputs perfectly, but while getting values from database(postgresql) it showing **"DataError"** I have taken input as alphanumeric in HTML form

here are my code:

in model.py i have written code for databese to make columns

model.py

```
class Admin(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(1000), primary_key=True )
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

in this auth.py I writen code for POST methods for signup and login

auth.py

```
@auth.route('/admin')
def admin():
    return render_template('admin.html')


@auth.route('/admin', methods=['POST'])
def admin_post():
    id = request.form.get('id')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    remember = True if request.form.get('remember') else False

admins = Admin.query.filter_by(id=id).first()

# check if the user actually exists
# take the user-supplied password, hash it, and compare it to the hashed password in the database
if not admins or not check_password_hash(admins.password, password):
    flash('Please check your login details and try again.')
    # if the user doesn't exist or password is wrong, reload the page
    return redirect(url_for('auth.admin'))

# if the above check passes, then we know the user has the right credentials
login_user(admins, remember=remember)
return redirect(url_for('main.adminOP'))


 @auth.route('/admin-signup')
 def adminsignup():
     return render_template('admin-signup.html')


 @auth.route('/admin-signup', methods=['POST'])
 def adminsignup_post():
     id = request.form.get('id')
     email = request.form.get('email')
     name = request.form.get('name')
     password = request.form.get('password')
     timestamp = datetime.now()

# if this returns a admin, then the email already exists in database
admins = Admin.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

if admins:  # if a user is found, we want to redirect back to signup page so user can try again
    flash('Email address already exists')
    return redirect(url_for('auth.adminsignup'))

# create a new user with the form data. Hash the password so the plaintext version isn't saved.
new_admin = Admin(id=id, email=email, name=name,
                  password=generate_password_hash(password, method='sha256'), timestamp=timestamp)

# add the new user to the database
db.session.add(new_admin)
db.session.commit()

return redirect(url_for('auth.admin'))
```

The error caught in trace back is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type 
integer: "B1"
LINE 3: WHERE person.id = 'B1'
                          ^

[SQL: SELECT person.id AS person_id, person.email AS person_email, person.password AS person_password, 
person.name AS person_name, person.timestamp AS person_timestamp
FROM person
WHERE person.id = %(pk_1)s]
[parameters: {'pk_1': 'B1'}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/9h9h)
```

Here B1 is id

admin-signup.html

As I said earlier I have used alhapanumeric in input field

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="column is-4 is-offset-4">
    <h3 class="title has-text-info">Sign Up</h3>
    <div class="box">
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
        <div class="notification is-danger">
            {{ messages[0] }}. Go to <a href="{{ url_for('auth.admin') }}">login page</a>.
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        <form method="POST" action="/admin-signup">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input is-large" type="text" name="id" placeholder="Your ID" autofocus="" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"><span
                        class="icon is-small is-left">
                        
                    </span>
                    <small> Remember: ID is you employee number </small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input is-large" type="email" aria-required="true" name="email" placeholder="Email"
                        autofocus=""><span class="icon is-small is-left">
                        
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input is-large" type="text" aria-required="true" name="name" placeholder="Name"
                        autofocus=""><span class="icon is-small is-left">
                        
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input is-large" type="password" aria-required="true" name="password"
                        placeholder="Password"><span class="icon is-small is-left">
                        
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="button is-block is-info is-large is-fullwidth">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

admin.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="column is-4 is-offset-4">
    <h3 class="title has-text-info">Admin Login</h3>
    <div class="box">
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
        <div class="notification is-danger">
            {{ messages[0] }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        <form method="POST" action="/admin">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input is-large" type="text" name="id" placeholder="Your ID" autofocus="" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"><span
                        class="icon is-small is-left">
                        
                    </span>
                    <small> HINT: ID is you employee number </small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input is-large" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password"><span
                        class="icon is-small is-left">
                        
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button class="button is-block is-info is-large is-fullwidth">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

After editing code i got this same error caught in debugging
[image]

this is person model

```html
class person(UserMixin, db.Model):
    # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

Comment: I would guess it's because the `id` field is integer and you're trying to pass through a string. Which in auth.py line is the error getting called on?

Comment: yes i am trying to pass string to id

Comment: Looking at the error you posted `invalid input syntax for type 
integer: "B1"` - notice it says *type integer* and not *type string*, but in your db model the `id` column is defined as a string. There's a discrepancy somewhere: the line that is causing the error will probably give more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the column `id` from your `person` model is an Integer, not a string. Your `load_user` function queries the `person` model providing a key `B1`, which can not be converted to Integer.

If you intend to query your `Admin` model and *also* query your `person` model depending on who is logged, you should add an identifier in your user session during login and retrieve it in the `load_user` function. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47973490/multiple-user-for-flask-login) for more details.

But if you need to treat your users differently (User#1 is an admin but User#2 is not), you should really consider using a boolean flag in your model, something like this:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(1000), primary_key=True )
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    # ...
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

You should really avoid having two user's models with different types of keys, it can get really messy over time.

If your Flask app tend to grow and have multiple kind of users, you should consider adopt the concept of 'user roles'. Check out [Flask-Principal](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/) for this.

### Old Answer

The issue is probably because your model and your database aren't synchronized. In some point the development processes you probably had `id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)` then you ran `db.create_all()` and then altered the id to `id = db.Column(db.String(1000), primary_key=True)`.

In simple words, Flask believes that id is a string, but PostgreSQL is sure that it is an int. Just to be sure, you could check the DDL of the table `person` with:

```
pg_dump -U your_user your_database -t person --schema-only
```

Note that flask/flask-sqlalchemy does not do automatic migrations, after changing your model you should recreate the database or apply the changes manually (the choice is up to you).

Comment: [Flask-Alembic](https://flask-alembic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is the de-facto solution for performing migrations with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @magnun-leno sir, i have dropped table and created new table it took id as string in db

Comment: @Vamsee. I just noticed that in the screenshot you are querying the person model, not the Admin model. Can you please add the definition of the Person model?

Comment: Yeah I have added person model code image in the question

Comment: I believe we may have found the issue @Vamsee.. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for patience and humbleness sir I will check with new answer.

Comment: As you linked to other question actually I need to query both user and admin it means multiuser